# External neighbors

Tags: scripting

I have this mesh with selected vertices.

[Mesh http://imageshack.com/a/img661/3861/yKrabj.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/3861/yKrabj.png)

I want to do a script that automatically gives for every selected vertice, his neighbors (vertices indices) that are external to the selection. For example, some neighbors of several selected vertices that respect the conditions :

[Neighbors http://imageshack.com/a/img537/172/wq2m2M.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/172/wq2m2M.png)

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: How would you formalize the criterion of which verts to choose? Further away from the object/selection center? Higher total edge length (don't think this will work except for a very few, very simple meshes)?

Comment: As you can see, i have a hole in this mesh. The user has to select approximatively a border of the hole.  
The criterion is for the neighbor to not be on the same side as the hole (the selection is between the neighbor and the hole). 
Being furthest away from the selection center do not work as a method if the user didn't select the border well (because of the curvature of the mesh' border).

Comment: It's not really well formalized but that's the problem :p